# Best way to simulate a server which randomly sends alarms

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Here's what I need to do:

I need to simulate a server, which sends alarms at random intervals, i.e. after 2 secs, then after 4, after 10 but always within some sort of range.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Here's my fist idea:

1.) Choose a random value between 0 and 10.
2.) Sleep for that amount of time
3.) Send an alarm to the client
4.) Repeat forever (i.e. while (`true`))

Comment: What is "some sort of range"?

Comment: Looks good. Differences could be only in the way of choosing the random value and about "sleep a bit" or using a Timer or similar for this.

Comment: It sounds like you already had a great plan. Did you try it first and fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea doesn't sound so bad. Of course, you could go a more sophisticated path using timers and signals, but it depends on the requirements and using simply sleep() is maybe the fastest and easiest way for your purposes. Go for it :)

Comment: How would I achieve the same result using Timers?

Comment: Define a timer that calls a function. In the function redefine the timer with a different interval.

Answer (score 1):

For range 4-10 seconds, choose a random value 0..6 (10-4), add 4, sleep this amount of seconds (or get current time, add the value, and loop with a short sleep rechecking the time), send alarm, rinse, repeat.